# access multiple files through a symbolic link

Tags: unix, hyperlink, named-pipes, cat

I am working with multiple large data files that I need to concatenate to input to a program. Unfortunately this program doesn't take stdin as input. 
An option would be to concatenate the multiple files and give the new file as input to the program, however this would (temporarily) require a lot of disk space, so I am searching for a more elegant option. 
Is there a UNIX way to create a link or file that would not include the whole dataset, but rather transparently redirect to a concatenation of all input files?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could it be possible to use a named pipe to do this?

Comment: mkfifo - make FIFOs (named pipes) , do a man for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it to work as I wished:

```
mkfifo my_pipe
cat file1 file2 > my_pipe &
my_program my_pipe
rm my_pipe
```

Thanks for the tips!